# How to fetch values from one function and transfer it to another?

Tags: c, function

The first function is able to make new account. I want to store that new_acc **name and DOB** and transfer it to another function. So when I call the **name** in second function, it should check that name, if present then give me access.

**One function**

```
int new_acc(FILE *fp, char *name, size_t namesize, char *dob, size_t dobsize){
    char data[8][51];
    int done = 0;
    int repeat = 0;

    while (!done) {
        if (repeat) {
            if (! allowmore())
                break;}
        repeat = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
            if (scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[i]) != 1) {
                done = 1;
                break;}
        }
        if (!done) { fprintf(fp, "%s %s\n", data[0], data[1]); }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**Another function**

```
int list_view(char *name, char *dob){
    printf("For person details, please enter the person name: \n");
    FILE * fr = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt","r");

    printf("Enter your Name: ");
    if (scanf("%50s", name) != 1){       // Giving access through this 
       perror("Error while reading!");    // code
       return 0;}

    char ch[100];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++){

        if(fr != NULL){
            while((ch[index] = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){
               if(ch[index] == ' ') {
                   ch[index] = '\0';
                   printf("Here is your %s: %s\n",listing[i], ch);
                   index = 0;
                   i++;}
               else { index++; }
           }
           fclose(fr);
        }
        else{ printf("Unable to read file."); }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, are you saying you are getting a compiler error?

Comment: I just want to fetch from text file, the name if it is present in text file then a user should be allowed to get access.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be mindful of the [scope](https://blog.miyozinc.com/c-programming/c-scope-lifetime/) of your variables. As a refresher:

> The scope of a variable is the part of the program within which the variable can be used. So, the scope describes the visibility of an identifier within the program.

The `data` variable is declared locally inside `new_acc` and not returned, which means that it is not visible outside the function.

To clarify this point, consider your `listing` array. You access it within both `new_acc` and `list_view` despite not passing it into either function. This leads me to believe that it is declared globally (outside any functions). If you want `name` to be visible in `list_view` you must similarly make it global or return it from `new_acc`.

note: the link I included also discusses lifetime of variables which is equally important to consider

Comment: Yeah I declared global variable listing but my point is that the first function saves the names and dobs in text file. So I want a registered user to enter his/her name and if that name is present in text file, then I could give access. In global variable all values are present in code. But I want to fetch from text file.

Comment: @BilalKhan have you verified that the data is written to the text file as you expect?

Comment: It is written. Yeah. It is big program which I am working in.

Comment: @BilalKhan which variable is undeclared?

Comment: my point is that the first function saves the names and dobs in text file. So I want a registered user to enter his/her name and if that name is present in text file, then I could give access. In global variable all values are present in code. But I want to fetch from text file.

Comment: @BilalKhan I understand, but information about what the compiler is telling you will help us figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Compiler is not giving me any message. Instead If I type any name even if it is not present in text file, it reads and show me. I want it to stop and just give me access if it is present in text file.

Comment: @BilalKhan I looked through `list_view` and I don't see anything that compares `name` against anything in the file. Which part of the code is supposed to do that?